# Probability question that includes proving limits.

Tags: probability

> There's $n$ cards which have two sides, black and white. 
> in the beginning, the cards are all turned on their black side. In every round, we choose randomly and independently from other rounds, one card from all the $n$ cards, if the card is on on it's black side, then we flip it, else we do nothing. 
> Let $T_n$ be the random variable that counts the number of rounds until all of the cards are on their white side,
>
> knowing that $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(T_n > (1+\epsilon)*n*\ln(n))=0$ (This was the first part of the question to prove, and I was able to do it using Markov's inequality). 
> Now we say that a card can be flipped again even if it was flipped before, 
> For $m\ge 1$,
> we define $T_n^m$ to be the number of rounds until all of the cards have been flipped Atleast $m$ times. show that: 
> $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(T^m_n>(1+\epsilon)*n*\ln(n)) = 0$, for every $\epsilon > 0$.

To be honest, I have no idea about how to do the second part of the question, I tried to link between $T_n$ and $T_n^m$ but It's just not working for me, for example, I tried to think of $m*T_n$ as the maximum of $T_n^m$, but I'm not really sure about that, and I'm not even sure that it helps me solve this. 
I would really appreciate any help in proving that limit, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you set $a(m,n)=\mathbb{E}(T_n^m)$ then use total law of expectation to say $$a(m+1,n)=a(m,n)+a(1,n)$$ You can compute $a(1,n)$ pretty easily and use this recurrence relation to establish a formula for $a(m,n)$. I'm not sure about this approach. Just a thought.